# Asynchronous callback : always an event-loop?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am studying asynchronism in different programming languages / implementations.
(I might be wrong on the assumption I am about to draw)

For example Java is synchronous.
But a caller object can use `Thread` to asynchronously run a callee object (in parallel).
At some point, the caller and callee might synchronize.
This synchronization assure that :

1. the execution order is correct
2. the memory isn't accessed concurrently

On the other hand, node.js runs Javascript inside an event-loop, and provides asynchronous I/O functions.
If the caller calls an asynchronous function, it provides a callback to execute after, which assures 1.
And because Javascript execution is single-threaded, there is non concurrency, and no need for memory synchronization, which assures 2.

I am wondering, is there an alternative implementation than an event-loop to provide asynchronism with callback ?
I would like to know of even the most atypical implementations.

Comment: I am not sure if Reactive programming is one of the alternatives here.

Comment: Javascript has webworkers also which are threads.  It prevents the need for memory synchronization by preventing webworkers from directly accessing any of the same objects as the main thread or any other webworker and using messaging (via the event loop) to communicate or pass data which provides automatic memory synchronization.

Comment: @etnbrd Are you looking for alternatives in JS only? In Java you have for example [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (async/callback using threads) and [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/)/[Akka](http://akka.io/) (mix of event-loop with threading).